# How to restructure a latex document in vim to force 80 char limit lines and fix indentation?

Tags: vim, latex

I'm working with other's in writing up assignments for a course and all the documents I receive have zero indentation and have lines that extend up to 200 characters on occasion. It sort of looks like this but imagine many more blocks that are flattened to the left.

```
\begin{enumeration}
\item thing 1 and ...a comment that extends to 200 characters
\item thing 2
\begin{enumeration}
\item subthing 2-2 and ... a comment that extends to 200 characters
\item subthing 2-3
\end{enumeration}
\end{enumeration}
```

I understand that people have different styles but its hard for me to quickly look at this and make sense of it.

I can fix indentation with

```
gg=G
```

I'm not sure how to wrap lines that have extended beyond 80 characters or if both of these can be done in a single command.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap lines in vim by using:

```
:set wrap
```

To make it so words are not broken between lines:

```
:set wrap linebreak nolist
```

Answer (score 0):

The following commands will limit the chars

1.

```
:%!fold -sw80
```

2.

```
:set textwidth=80
```

Then you can reformat your text by marking it (`visual` mode) and select the entire text and type `gq`.

For indentation, as you have all coded latex document

```
%s/^\([^\\]\)/^I\1/gec
```

`^I` is tab